# Filtering dictionary inside an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6, array-filter

I have An Array With Dictionary example :

```
[{
    "CATEGORYNAME" = "name0";
    "CATEGORYSUBID" = 2;
    "ID" = 1;
}, {
    "CATEGORYNAME" = "name1";
    "CATEGORYSUBID" = 2;
    "ID" = 2;
}, {
    "CATEGORYNAME" = "name2";
    "CATEGORYSUBID" = 0;
    "ID" = 3;
}]
```

I Used to Filter it in Objective C Like this

```
JSON_data = [[[Global SharedData]Categorys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(CATEGORYSUBID == %@)", Filter]];
```

i tried To Use Array Filter but not Succeed

```
var JSON_data = Global.SharedData().Categorys
JSON_data = JSON_data.filter( ?????
```

JSON_data is has all data i have print it with Printin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Filtering a dictionary would be simple like below. We filter ages that are below 30.

```
var visitors = [["age" : 22], ["age" : 41], ["age" : 23], ["age" : 30]]

var filteredVisitors = visitors.filter({
    $0["age"] < 30 //access the value to filter
})

println(filteredVisitors)
//[["age" : 22], ["age" : 23]]
```

More info here: [Filtering a Swift Array of Dictionaries or Object property](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/filtering-swift-array-dictionaries-object-property/)

Answer (score 5):

This looks like just a simple question in how to translate.  Your best option is to go through the various Sessions from WWDC, but a literal translation is:

```
let categories = Global.SharedData().Categorys()
JSON_data = categories.filter({
    if let subid = $0["CATEGORYSUBID"] {
        return subid == filter
    } else {
        return false
    }
})
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to post a lot more information about how Global, SharedData, Categorys and JSON_data.

Comment: i Think There is no filteredArrayUsingPredicate in swift and the result of your code is : 'AnyObject[]' does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'

Comment: Are Global, SharedData and Categorys in swift, or objective-C?

Comment: They are in the objective-C i have import them and the array are filled

Comment: Working now `myCategories = JSON_data.filter({
            if let subid : AnyObject! = $0["CATEGORYSUBID"] {
                return subid as NSObject == self.myFilter
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
`

Comment: Where  did you make use of "Predicate" above code @DavidBerry

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha I didn't, apparently I changed my approach at some point :)